# Is there an open source tool to distinguish speech from song?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am interested in a source code tool that given as input an audio file is able to identify if the audio file contains clear speech (no song in background).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such source code exist. The reason is that your task is not precisely defined. Is the single drum beat on the background count as a song on background? Are multiple beats count? What if piano is playing?

Ideally you should have get some samples of music you want to distinguish, i.e. not try to detect everything but some specific cues of music style like drums.

You can train a GMM classifier to distinguish clean speech from speech with music on background, but that is non-trivial task. You need some training data to teach computer what is song and what is not.

You can find example code here: https://github.com/danstowell/smacpy